# Different behaviour when stopping container (docker stop vs drain)

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I experience a strange behaviour with docker.

For some reason a service needs two attempts to start on a different node when I use `docker service update --availability drain myHost` on the host where this service was running before.

When doing the same with `docker stop containerId` the service will start on the first attempt.

I don't think that docker is responsible for our service to require multiple attempts to start, but there has to be a different behaviour on stopping containers when a node is in drain mode vs docker stop and I hope that finding this difference will point me to the right direction to find the problem with our services.

To make clearer what I do I will provide a short example over here:

1. Initial Situation

> Node1 (active):
>
> - Service1 Running
>
> Node2 (active):
>
> - Service2 Running

2. `docker service update --availability drain Node2`

> Node1 (active):
>
> - Service1 Running
> - Service2 Running (after two attempts to start)
>
> Node2 (drain):

3. `docker service update --availability active Node2`

> Node1 (active):
>
> - Service1 Running
> - Service2 Running (nothing changes since no re-balancing happens)
>
> Node2 (active):

4. `(onNode1)$: docker stop serivce2`

> Node1 (active):
>
> - Service1 Running
>
> Node2 (active):
>
> - Service2 Running (after first attempt)

The behaviour is the same when forcing a service not to run on a node by adding a constraint.

1. Initial Situation

> Node1 (active):
>
> - Service1 Running
>
> Node2 (active):
>
> - Service2 Running

2. `docker service update --constraint-add "node.hostname != Node2" Service2`

> Node1 (active):
>
> - Service1 Running
> - Service2 Running (after two attempts to start)
>
> Node2 (drain):

3. `docker service update --constraint-rm "node.hostname != Node2" Service2`

> Node1 (active):
>
> - Service1 Running
> - Service2 Running (nothing changes since no re-balancing happens)
>
> Node2 (drain):

4. `docker service update --constraint-add "node.hostname != Node1" Service2`

> Node1 (active):
>
> - Service1 Running
>
> Node2 (drain):
>
> - Service2 Running (after two attempts to start)

I can't find any difference documented, so I hope there is someone here on stackoverflow who has an idea what docker is doing differently.